# Variable column name on function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm new to pgsql but have I have 8 years of experience with MSSQL, what i'm trying achieve is: create a function to apply this remove invalid data from names, it will remove all special characters, numbers and accents, keeping only spaces and a-Z characters, I want to use it on columns of different tables, but I cant really find what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_validaNome (VARCHAR(255)) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR(255) AS 
SELECT  regexp_replace(unaccent($1), '[^[:alpha:]\s]', '', 'g')
COMMIT
```

If I run

```
SELECT  regexp_replace(unaccent(column_name), '[^[:alpha:]\s]', '', 'g') 
from TableA
```

my code runs fine. I don't know exactly what is wrong with the function code.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported or maintained](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  - you should plan an upgrade **now**.

Answer (score 3):

That's not how functions are written in Postgres.

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) the function's body must be passed as a string and you need to specify which language the function is written in. Functions can be written in SQL, PL/pgSQL, PL/python, PL/perl and many others. There is also no need to reference parameters by position. Passing a [dollar quoted](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) string makes writing the function body easier.

For what you are doing, a simple [SQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) is enough. It's also unnecessary to use an arbitrary character limit like 255 (which does have any performance or storage advantages over any other defined max length). So just use `text`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_validanome (p_input text) 
  RETURNS text 
AS 
$body$ --<< string starts here. 
  SELECT regexp_replace(unaccent(p_input), '[^[:alpha:]\s]', '', 'g'); --<< required ; at the end
$body$ --<< string ends here
language sql
immutable; --<< required ; at the end
```

Comment: Thank  you, a_horse_with_no_name, your  explanation along with the code did  help  me  understand how to handle functions.